# Parse JSON array to tabular format in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a JSON object like this

```
'{
    "car": [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"],
    "car owner": ["Alex", "Tom", "Jane"]
}'
```

I need to parse it to tabular format in SQL Server

```
Car   | Car owner
Ford    Alex
BMW     Tom
Fiat    Jane
```

I've tried

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (
  [Car] NVARCHAR(50) '$.Car[0]',
  [Car owner] NVARCHAR(50) '$."Car owner"[0]'
)
```

It returns the first item in the array but I cannot return all records with just `'$.Car'` and `'$."Car owner"'` in the same `WITH` clause.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version and are `car` and `car owner` the only possible keys in the input JSON? Thanks.

Comment: Mine is 2016, car and car owner just examples, my real JSON has approximately 60 keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to open each array as a table with a separate `OPENJSON` call and join them by the generated key to match up the positions;

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{
    "car": [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"],
    "car owner": ["Alex", "Tom", "Jane"]
}'

SELECT a.value car, b.value owner
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.car') a
JOIN OPENJSON(@json, '$."car owner"') b
  ON a."key" = b."key"
```

This will give the result;

```
car     owner
-------------
Ford    Alex
BMW     Tom
Fiat    Jane
```

[A DBfiddle to test around with](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=872ab817b6e91c484cd48aa071c38811)

Comment: Thanks, it works for the example, but is there any way to make it work with JSON data which has many columns without specify each column in the OPENJSON, for example 50 columns?

Comment: @KhoaĐỗ There may be, however there is no simple syntax that I'm aware of. The simpler version would be to restructure the JSON in a more straight forward (and arguably more readable) "object" manner as `[{"car":"Ford", "owner":"Alex"}, {"car":"BMW", "owner":"Tom"}, {"car":"Fiat", "owner":"Jane"}]` which makes the query trivial. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d5a73e03df8de1777473265c1952634

Comment: Thank you, but my data is dynamic which I have no idea about the structure at run time so I cannot transform it into c# object